# ¿Cómo ejecutar un script php desde una funcion php

Tags: php, funciones, script

tengo esta función en la cual necesito pasar una variable como parámetro, luego hacer que se ejecute otro script para generar un pdf , luego llamar el valor que se almaceno con la ejecución de ese script impresionPdf.
mi funcion es asi:

```
public function mostrarPdf($chatId, $unidad) {
            
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['unidad']= "$unidad";// envio unidad a impresionPdf.php
            // ejecutar impresionPDF.PHP

         }
```

DESDE YA MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: Quizás es esto lo que buscas? [How to call function of one php file from another php file and pass parameters to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8104998/how-to-call-function-of-one-php-file-from-another-php-file-and-pass-parameters-t)

Comment: Con la poca información que das en tu pregunta, creo que incluir el script sería suficiente: `include 'impresionPDF.php';`